# GUI with socket in another thread

Tags: c#

I want to create a WinForm application that must draw data coming from a socket.

I want to put the code reading from a socket in a separate thread and I am aware of the `InvokeRequired/BeginInvoked` pattern.

Which type of C# thread is the most suited for my purpose considering the WinForm scenario? Is it enough a common `System.Threading.Thread` entirely dedicated to reading data from socket or other types like `BackgroundWorker`? Or should I consider something else?

Comment: No signature (or greeting) necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this thread running for a long time?  If you need it to run for a long time, and if you don't need to directly interact with a GUI (maybe cache data to a buffer), then I would use System.Threading.Thread.  I have been using BackgroundWorker and found that, while it allows you to update the GUI via its event, it uses the .NET threadpool.  The threadpool has a finite amount of threads available, so if you need to use Windows Workflow or lots of delegates via BeginInvoke, you could hurt application performance by tying up too many threadpool threads.

Comment: Tying up a Pool-thread won't be any slower (or better) than creating a new one.

Comment: Yes! It will run for hours with a huge amount of data received + it needs to update also the GUI. I definitely will use a cache buffer + refresh Gui each n milliseconds since the ThreadPool will be definetly filled up quickly. Thanks!

Comment: @Henk: I have been under the impression that if you use up the threads in the threadpool, then you won't be able to launch another threadpool thread until it becomes available.  If you can't do this, then you can't do any work.  By that definition, you would hurt application performance, no?

Comment: Dave, that advice is slightly outdated, the MaxThreads is by default 2000 or more now. The ThreadPool will allocate them when needed. But for long running threads you might as well create a dedicated one.

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread();
// do threadstart parameters or whatever
workerThread.IsBackground = true;
workerThread.Start();
```

This should be sufficient...you can even set it's priority if that is a concern.

I don't particularly care for BackgroundWorker. Even though the events are helpful, I don't need the help. I find it limiting because I use a lot of asynchronous methods (Action/Func).

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) states the process with Background Worker:

> To set up for a background operation, add an event handler for the DoWork event. Call your time-consuming
>   operation in this event handler. To start the operation, call RunWorkerAsync. To receive notifications of 
>   progress updates, handle the ProgressChanged  event. To receive a notification when the operation is 
>   completed, handle the RunWorkerCompleted  event.

It just seems a lot simpler to use System.Threading.Thread.

Comment: Hi dboarman! Thanks for your reply and I agree with you! I asked this since I realized only today about this helper class but I didn't understand the particular reason for doing that. This class is always mentioned in the GUI scenario as helper class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the APM pattern, ie

```
 mySocket.BeginReceive(..., myCallBack);
```

But it is not my favorite pattern. I would use the ThreadPool, possibly through a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Thanks Henk! I realized that probably I will have problem with it due to large number of data received.

Comment: @Abruzzo, For the Threading part (how many threads) the amount of data does not matter. But the number of sockets (connections) does.